# Linux Serial Port прослушка

Tags: c++, linux, c, codeblocks, serial

Добро.
Есть программа, которая настраивает /dev/ttyS0.
Она отправляет сообщения по этому порту.
Подскажите, как прослушать входящие и исходящие сообщения на этот порт.

cat /dev/ttyS0 работает только, когда я подключаю девайс, которым хочу управлять и он шлет на порт свои сообщения, их я вижу.

А вот что моя программа пытается отправить на порт я не могу отследить.

Создаю указатель FHandel на порт /dev/ttyS0, с необходимыми настройками.

```
  int FHandle;

  void Uart::Open()
  {
     int flags |= O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY;

     FHandle = open("/dev/ttyS0", flags);

     if(FHandle == InvalidHandleValue)
        throw UartExcept;

     termios newSettings;
     bzero(&newSettings, sizeof(termios));

     cfsetospeed(&newSettings, B9600);
     cfsetispeed(&newSettings, B9600);

     newSettings.c_cflag |= CS8;
     newSettings.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL|CS8|CREAD);
     newSettings.c_cflag &= ~(CRTSCTS|CSIZE|PARENB);
     newSettings.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
     newSettings.c_cc[VTIME] = 3;
     newSettings.c_iflag = INPCK | IGNPAR;

     if(tcsetattr(FHandle, TCSANOW, &newSettings) == -1)
        throw UartException;
  }
```

В определенном месте отправляю буфер

```
  UInt32 Uart::Write(const Byte *_inputBuffer, UInt32 _bufferOffset, UInt32 _numberOfBytesToWrite)
  {
     ssize_t result;
     if (FWOverlapped == nullptr)
        result = write(FHandle, _inputBuffer + _bufferOffset, _numberOfBytesToWrite);

     return (UInt32)result;
  }
```

Как перехватить эти сообщения, которые я шлю, с помощью программы?

Спасибо за ваше время.

Comment: Сами отправляете и не знаете что отправляете?

Comment: Можете сделать loopback. В простейшем случае когда не используются сигнальные линии достаточно замкнуть два контакта TX и RX между собой. Вообще в интернете полно инструкций как  это сделать. Тогда всё, что пишите в порт, будите тут же получать обратно на входе порта.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете протестировать программу с помощью псевдотерминалов. Например, `/dev/pts/*`. Подробнее описано в [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal).

Comment: У меня почему-то отсутствуют данные псевдотерминалы.

Comment: Попробуйте поискать /dev/pty* или /dev/pts*.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте утилиту `strace` для просмотра системных вызовов программы. Возможна фильтрация по функциям. Для вашей цели возможно будет достаточно:

```
strace -e write -s макс_длина_буфера программа
```